# body background image position issue in css

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-position

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0px; padding:0;
    background:url(http://custdemos.com/synverse_portfolio/images/safercab_mobi.png) no-repeat left bottom;
    height:100%
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="do">
X Content 
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to put that background image on body bottom, plz if anybody knows this issue tel me.

Comment: Thank you Vucko and Swarnamayee finally i got solution for that, plz check my answer.

Comment: background-attachment:fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a min height to body. Here is the corrected jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dbF3K/20/). Following is also modified css

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0;
    background:url(http://custdemos.com/synverse_portfolio/images/safercab_mobi.png) no-repeat left bottom;
    min-height:500px;
}
```